# GooglePlus class doesn't have login function from Cordova plugin in Ionic app

Tags: cordova, google-plus, ionic3

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/implementing-google-plus-sign-in-with-oauth-2-0-in-ionic-2/) for using GooglePlus login within an Ionic app. I have installed the plugin by [Eddy Verbruggen](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) and according to the tutorial I should have this line at the top of `home.ts`.

```
import { GooglePlus } from 'ionic-native';
```

Ionic complained when I tried to build that. Changing it to this helped

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
```

However now the following code won't transpile

```
GooglePlus.login({.....
```

Because "Property 'login' does not exist on type 'typeof GooglePlus'". Using WebStorm I can control-click on GooglePlus and it takes me to the class definition in `node_modules/@ionic-native/google-plus` and it shows that the class clearly has a function called login.

[image]

- npm 5.5.1
- Ionic 3.19.0
- Cordova 7.1.0
- OS X 10.12.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This changes I needed from the tutorial are partly detailed in [Ionic's docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-plus/)

1) Add GooglePlus to the constructor

```
constructor(private googlePlus: GooglePlus) { }
```

2) change `GooglePlus.login()` to `this.googlePlus.login`

3) Import GooglePlus and add it as a provider in `app.module.ts`

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';
```

...

```
providers: [
    GooglePlus
]
```